# Pass a parameter to a new window php

Tags: php, javascript, window

I'm opening a new php page from my main page using js:

```
window.open ('second.php','_self',false);
```

I have a string on the parent page, `tmpstr`, how can I access the value of `tmpstr` from second.php? I can't use `GET` because the string is huge.

Answer (score 5):

You can store it in the $_SESSION variable.

```
$_SESSION["passedParameter"] = $hugeString;
```

And then, on the second page, you can use

```
$hugeString = $_SESSION["passedParameter"];
```

Just don't forget to add `session_start();` at the beginning of both pages, in order for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

use the `window.opener` property in javascript

in the first page

```
window.tmpstr = tmpstr;
window.open ('second.php','_self',false);
```

in second.php

```
alert(window.opener.tmpstr)
```

I assume you want to access this in javascript, not in php.

Comment: This is more like what I want.  It looks really simple but I cannot get it to work.  the alert in the second window won't popup.

Comment: When I change the '_self' to 'blank' it works...when its '_self' the parent window goes away